# PostgreSQL duplicating rows with two column duplicates

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In PostgreSQL I am looking for an answer to the following problem.
There are two columns providing data about 'start' and 'end', together with a 'date' column. Currently the date column only exists once with 'start' and 'end' being filled with possibilities.

I am looking for the possibility to create a 'start' and 'end' column with unique values, but with duplicating dates.

current:

```
id  date          start    end
1   2017-03-13    a        [null]
2   2017-03-14    [null]   a
3   2017-03-14    b        [null]
4   2017-03-16    [null]   b
5   2017-03-16    c        c
```

wish:

```
id  date          start    end
1   2017-03-13    a        [null]
2   2017-03-14    [null]   a
3   2017-03-14    b        [null]
4   2017-03-16    [null]   b
5   2017-03-16    c        [null]
6   2017-03-16    [null]   c
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: create unique index on the start and end columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reactie Mokadillion. When I do that I get the error `ERROR: could not create unique index "test_idx" DETAIL: Key (start, end)=(c, c) is duplicated.' This is what I do expect but do not see how it could resolve my issue.

Comment: as below, end is a keyword and will need to be double quoted, best use a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, and you want exactly one of `start` and `"end"` to be set, and the combination with `date` unique, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
   ADD CHECK(start IS NULL AND "end" IS NOT NULL
          OR start IS NOT NULL AND "end" IS NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tab (date, COALESCE(start, "end"));
```